Why does the python libpostal expansion only output a subset of possible expansions?
Example 1:
>>> len(expand_address('10 N ORANGE AVE 10th fl ORLANDO FL 12345'))
100

This gets North, Avenue, Floor,... etc. just fine.
Example 2:
Now, if I add STE 2 to the mix it stops midway:
>>> len(expand_address('10 N ORANGE AVE 10th fl ste 2 ORLANDO FL 12345'))
24

In fact it has duplicated, redundant entries:
10 n orange ave 10th fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10th fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10th fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10th fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10 fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10 fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10 fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10 fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10 fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10 fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10 fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10 fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10th fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10th fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10th fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10th fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10 fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10 fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10 fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10 fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10 fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10 fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10 fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345
10 n orange ave 10 fl ste 2 orlando fl 12345

The total number of expansions should've increased but they didn't? Why not? The latter doesn't even expand N -> North or ave -> avenue.
Why this abrupt halting of expansions and what might be the way around it?
